# Resize option of the jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have read the resizable of jQuery UI. after that i use the code and got success. but now i do not understand the "option" in the line

```
    $( ".selector" ).resizable({ handles: 'n, e, s, w' });

Get or set the handles option, after init.

    //getter
    var handles = $( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "handles" );
    //setter
    $( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "handles", 'n, e, s, w' );
```

in the example what is option. perticularly last line `$( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "handles", 'n, e, s, w' );`.

Comment: I'm awfully sorry, but I don't have a clue what you're talking about. Can you form a concrete question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`option` is a method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#method-option). jQuery UI methods tend to be executed by calling the widget function (in this case `resizable`) with a string representing the method name as the first argument.

The second argument is the name of the option you want to get/set, and the third argument, if present, is the value to set the option to.

In a similar way, you could enable or disable the widget:

```
$(".selector").resizable("enable"); //Call the enable method
$(".selector").resizable("disable"); //Call the disable method
$(".selector").resizable("option", "handles"); //Call the option method, get the handles option value
```

For example, if you wanted to know whether or not the `resizable` is enabled or not, you could do:

```
//If it's disabled, disabled == true. If not, disabled == false
var disabled = $(".selector").resizable("option", "disabled");

//After the following line, the resizable element will be in the opposite state
//(if it was enabled, it will be disabled, and vice versa)
$(".selector").resizable("option", "disabled", !disabled);
```

Comment: can you a give an example of that

Comment: i mean example of option method

Comment: You already have shown 2 examples in your question! Pass 2 arguments to get the value of the specified option. Pass the third argument as well to set the specified option to that value. I've updated my answer with a little example though.